# Dúvida em criptografia unescape

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Estou com esse script no site, mas esse pequeno trecho está criptografado e queria alterá-lo pois o mesmo é um email para contato. Quando altero essa parte que está criptografada, o texto fica embaralhado e sem sentido; como eu teria que proceder para que a alteração ficasse no formato certo?

```
        function contact() {
            prompt('You can contact us at:', unescape(('636f6e746163744069702d6170692e636f6d').replace(/(..)/g, '%$1')));
            return false
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Isso não é criptografia, muito longe disso. Para que seja uma criptografia ela ao menos deveria de ter uma chave, o que não existe.

---

Somente vendo o `636f6e746163744069702d6170692e636f6d` já diz que isso é um hexadecimal (afinal vai de 0 até F), com quase total certeza.

O `unescape` funciona usando `%` seguindo de dois dígitos hexadecimal ("%HH", onde `HH` é o hexadecimal), assim como outras linguagem usam o `\x` (acredito que a maioria das outras também use esse formato). Por esse motivo existe o `replace(/(..)/g, '%$1')`, justamente para adicionar os `%` a cada dois caracteres, tornando um hexadecimal válido para o Javascript.

---

Portanto, o e-mail é exatamente `contact@ip-api.com`. Se quiser alterar este e-mail basta codificar/converter o valor para hexadecimal, por exemplo usando:

```js
function hexx(str) {
  hex = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    hex += str.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
  }

  document.getElementsByTagName("exibe")[0].innerHTML = "unescape(('" + hex + "').replace(/(..)/g, '%$1'));";

}
```

```html
<input onkeyup="hexx(this.value)"><br>
<exibe></exibe>
```